# Can I delete my own question which has an answer awarded with a bounty?

Tags: support, bounties

Can I delete my own question which has an answer awarded with a bounty?

Comment: Does the answer have a positive score?

Comment: @Catija it has 0 score

Comment: Did you try to delete the question?

Comment: Its worth asking - why do you want to delete it? What's useful for you may be useful for others, and it seems unfair to the person who answered *and* got a bounty. You could, but should you? Clearly the question is useful to the other person.

Answer (score 3):

Bounty is not an upvote, it does not affect the answer's score, so the ordinary rules apply. As written in [the faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that):

> You can’t delete your own question when it:
>
> - has an upvoted answer, or
> - has an accepted answer, or
> - has multiple answers (even if there are no upvotes)

So if the question has one single answer, which didn't get any upvotes, and is not accepted, you can delete it even if that answer has been awarded a bouty.

Comment: Note: This may result in a flag from the user who loses their bounty award requesting it be undeleted, and a moderator will likely fulfill that request.

Comment: ow. I'd think that bounties would be protected.

Comment: @animuson still, this is technically possible, I can't and won't judge if it's ethical. In such case, a feature request should be started to add "bounty awarded" as reason to prevent OP from deleting.

Answer (score 1):

While there's an active bounty - I don't think you can. Its protected. Assuming that you've not met any of the other criteria (as per shadow wizard's answer), *once* the bounty is awarded (or not) you could.

I think its worth looking at the actual question, and well, what we're trying to achieve here. Its kind of an odd situation - the question's sitting at a negative score (for being too simple I presume). You have two answers with just high enough a score that they'd lose out of deleted (presumably because of the bounty?).

Since someone else has posted a bounty, clearly he finds the question useful (I don't have the reputation to check votesplits) - which is kind of the implicit criteria for questions being around.

With a pair of -3 questions on that site, deletion's actually more likely to push you towards a question ban (which is bad).

Quite literally no one benefits from the question being deleted.

Comment: With 2 answers OP can't delete anyway.